# connect two mcp3002 IC to raspberry pi3 model B

Tags: pi-3, analog-to-digital

I need use 4 sensor with analog output in raspberry pi3 . in my country we have only mcp3002. I can not get mcp3004.

how I can connect two mcp3002 to raspberry pi3 for read data from 4 analog sensor???
please help me

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/MCP3002-analog-to-digital-converter-ADC-to-Raspberry-Pi.php

Answer (score 5):

SPI is a bus.

Use the same connections between the Pi and the chips for Vcc, ground, MOSI, MISO, and SCLK.

Use CE0 for one chip and CE1 for the other.

The software uses the slave select line (CE0/CE1) to specify the chip to read at any one moment in time.

Comment: OK my friend @joan
but when I put CE0=1 to read from first chip . how I can select the sensor on first chip? every chip contain two sensors

Comment: @sode You need to read the datasheet to see the commands you send to read the various channels within the MCP3002.  The datasheet may look complicated but it has all the information you need and is a skill which you need to acquire.